# How to pass an ID parameter on an action link based on a dropdown list selection in ASP.NET MVC C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I cant seem to figure this out. I have a view page that's for adding a product to an order. There's a dropdown list where you select the product you want to add. Once you select a product, I have an onchange function that basically inserts the value of the Product ID into a hidden input field. Where I'm stuck is I have an action link that goes to a different controller and a different model so I can't just use the Model.ProductID when I use the id parameter. Is there a way to get the value of the input field that is essentially the ProductID value from the product selected and use that as the id parameter on the actionlink? The actionlink opens a product view that shows a pic of the product and the qty in stock. but when I click on the link, its not getting the id value of the product selected.

Here is the relevant part of my view page:

```
<div class="form-group">
<label class="lbl3">Product:</label><span class="required">&nbsp;*</span><label class="ddl1">@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ProductID, ViewBag.ProductID as SelectList, "--Select a Product--", new { @class = "form-control prod-ctl", @onChange = "selectedText(this)" })</label>
<input type="hidden" id="txt" name="poProduct" required />
<label class="lbl2">Qty Ordered:</label><span class="required">&nbsp;*</span><input type="text" inputmode="numeric" class="col-md-3 form-control qty-ctl" name="poQtyOrdered" id="poQtyOrdered" required />
<label class="chk-link"><a class='prod-modal chk-stock' href="@Url.Action("AmtInStock", "Products", new { id = "THIS IS WHERE IM STUCK" })"><span class="fa solid fa-search">&nbsp;<u>Check Stock</u></span></a></label>
```

```
<script>
    function selectedText(ddlitem) {
        var selvalue = ddlitem.value;
        var seltext = ddlitem.options[ddlitem.selectedIndex].innerHTML;
        $('#txt').val(selvalue);
    }
</script>
```

Here is my controller for the actionlink:

```
public ActionResult AmtInStock(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        var product = db.Products.Find(id);
        if (product == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return PartialView("AmtInStock", product);
    }
```

and lastly, here is the ddl code in controller for the main page:

```
ViewBag.ProductID = new SelectList(db.Products, "ProductID", "Product_Code");
```

So I need to be able to select a product in the dropdown list and if I click on the actionlink, I need to be able to get the value of that selected item to pass in the id parameter.

Thanks,
Kip M.

Comment: Rename the hidden field to id.

Comment: so change the name from "poProduct" to "id"? Then what do I do on my actionlink...do I put id = "id"?

Comment: No It should pick it up as the field will be called id and you already have it in action(int id)

Comment: I tried that and it didn't work. I'm not sure what to try next, I'm totally stumped.

Comment: Simplest and easiest option would be to create a simple model and use the model on the action.  See [For example](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/webapi/consume-web-api-post-method-in-aspnet-mvc)

Comment: So it has to be a "post" action? I don't want to have to create a new record since this link is only a view of the productID that was selected from the dropdown list. It will show you how much is in stock, etc. So when you select a product from the ddl, if you clicked on the link it would get the id from the product selected and display. Based on my code above, I don't know how I'd get this to be a post action. My begin form statement is for the main page "AddProduct", not the action for the link for the product view called "AmtInStock".

Comment: The article gives good example how to create the form using mvc in a page.  Yes it must be a post action to bind the id.  The other option is you use ajax to get the data from the server as json and create the UI yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I was finally able to figure out how to do this and get it working perfectly. This method doesn't require a post method. It will let you use the id value of the dropdown list selection in the action link. I had to use a javascript function that basically manually changes the href attribute to include the id value on the end. I had to give the actionlink an id which I named "chkID". Then whenever the dropdown list selection changes, it calls that elements id and changes the href Url Action with the new selections id value. Below is the new code that is working for me:

The view page:

```
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="lbl3">Product:</label><span class="required">&nbsp;* 
    </span><label class="ddl1">@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ProductID, ViewBag.ProductID as SelectList, "--Select a Product--", new { id = "ddlID", @class = "form-control prod-ctl", @onChange = "selectedText(this)" })</label>
    <a class="prod-modal chk-stock" href="@Url.Action("ProductLookup", "ProductOrders")" id="chkID"><span class="fa solid fa-search">&nbsp;<u>Check Availability</u></span></a>
    <input type="hidden" id="txt" name="poProduct" required />                               
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="lbl2">Qty Ordered:</label><span class="required">&nbsp;* 
    </span><input type="text" inputmode="numeric" class="col-md-3 form control qty-ctl" name="poQtyOrdered" id="poQtyOrdered" required />
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="submit" value="Add To Order" class="btn btn-info col-md-3" />
  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript">
      function selectedText(ddlitem) {
         var selvalue = ddlitem.value;
         var seltext = ddlitem.options[ddlitem.selectedIndex].innerHTML;
         $('#txt').val(selvalue);

         var checkID = document.getElementById("chkID");
         checkID.setAttribute("href", '@Url.Action("AmtInStock", "Products")/' + selvalue);
      }
  </script>
```